# MVC pass viewmodel view with viewmodel containing parent values and child list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

My application has multiple areas within one facility.  I am  trying to pass a single model to the view that contains facility values (facility_id, facility_name), and a list of areas.  I currently have the list of areas as a type of the entity model for the table (area_list).

My viewmodel is as follows:

```
 public class AreaView
{

    public string facility_name { get; set; }
    public int facility_id { get; set; }
    public int group_id { get; set; }

    public IList<area_list> areas { get; set; }

}
```

As an aside, I had originally tried setup the list of areas as a separate viewmodel (AreaS) instead of the model area_list, but I had other issues there so went back to directly referencing the for simplicity.  I am assuming this would be more appropriate...

My Controller:

```
     public ActionResult List(int id = 0)
    {

        var model = (from f in areaDB.facility_list
                     where f.facility_id == id
                     select new AreaView
                     {
                         facility_id = f.facility_id,
                         facility_name = f.facility_name,
                         areas = (from a in areaDB.area_list
                                  orderby a.area_name
                                  where a.facility_id == id
                                  select a).ToList()
                     });

        return View(model);
    }
```

My View (abbreviated):

```
@model SkyeEnergy.Models.AreaView
Facility: @Model.facility_name
@foreach (var item in Model.areas) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink(item.vendor_name,"Details","Area",new {id = item.vendor_id},null)

    </td>

</tr>
}
```

I have tried numerous variations to accomplish what's below, which has given me numerous errors, but the most recent is below:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[MyApp.Models.AreaView]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'MyApp.Models.AreaView'.

I understand that I am not passing the correct type for what the view is expecting, but I cannot seem to figure out:

1. Is the viewmodel setup correctly in the firstplace (how to mix values and a list of children
2. How to structure my linq query to get one AreaView object with
   all my data
3. Pass it appropriately (in the correct type) to my
   view

I have read about 45 posts on Stackoverflow, but can't seem to piece them together to accomplish what's above.  If anyone has a correct solution (or even a direction), I would be very appreciative.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not combine both object in the same query. I would do

1) Select AreaView where id = xxxx

2) Select Areas where id = xxxx

3) Assign areas to my AreaView

Example

```
AreaView model = GetAreaView(id);

model.Areas = GetAreas(id);

return View(model);
```

***Also, try the following for your current code***

```
return View(model.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Splitting out the queries did make it easier.  From your example, my first line of code did look a bit different, any issue with this?  `code var model = (from f in areaDB.facility_list
                              where f.facility_id == id
                              select new AreaView
                              {...`

Comment: Stepping over your code in debug mode, it would make it difficult to know the value of those pieces you put together. It makes your code simpler and easy to test when you break things down and couple them together

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add FirstOrDefault() at the end of your query to return the `AreaView`

```
public ActionResult List(int id = 0)
{

    var model = (from f in areaDB.facility_list
                 where f.facility_id == id
                 select new AreaView
                 {
                     facility_id = f.facility_id,
                     facility_name = f.facility_name,
                     areas = (from a in areaDB.area_list
                              orderby a.area_name
                              where a.facility_id == id
                              select a).ToList()
                 }).FirstOrDefault();

    return View(model);
}
```